# Which map can I use in J2me?

Tags: java-me, dictionary

I want to develop a map app i j2me for a college project.I want to display my location using lattitude and longitude as a marker. The map must be free as well.. Which map is best suited for my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose you can use any map service provider, be it google, bing or yahoo. A quick search revealed [how to use Bing map from JS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412551.aspx). You can search for similar resources on internet. Server side APIs are needed only when you need sophisticated logic to implement. In scenarios as simple as yours you can do it in JS alone and it will be free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [google map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html). You can detect location using GPS or Netowork aided detection. Here is a snapshot I used in my android app for my Location detection:

[image: Location]